# What is a good editor similar to Tex-Studio for Mac

Tags: editors

I have been using Tex-Studio under Ubuntu, but now I am starting to use MacBook Air.

What is a good choice of editor which is similar to Tex-Studio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TeX Studio is available for Mac and is certainly the editor most similar to TeX Studio.